Firebase error when testing on Android phone OS 13: No AppCheckProvider installed
I have the follow issue
Using Android Studio Giraffe with below settings -

compileSdk = 34
minSdkVersion 24
targetSdkVersion 33

Login to Firebase

Testing with Emulator with Android Studio Giraffe
I had no problem to logout and login firebase.

But Using USB-testing on Android phone with Android OS 13



Problem: Encountered
Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.

What I need to do?
Firebase error msg when login:
I  ViewPostIme pointer 0
I  ViewPostIme pointer 1
D  mReversing is false. Don't call initChildren.
I  Logging in as xxxxxxxr@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
W  Verification of java.lang.String com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzagz.zza() took 973.726ms (54.43 bytecodes/s) (3080B approximate peak alloc)
W  Verification of void com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzadp.zza(java.net.HttpURLConnection, com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzadm, java.lang.reflect.Type) took 6.463s (19.49 bytecodes/s) (5768B approximate peak alloc)

I  Skipped 10677 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D  mReversing is false. Don't call initChildren.
W  Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.

W  Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.

D  tagSocket(121) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
D  tagSocket(123) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
I  Compiler allocated 6917KB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
D  tagSocket(123) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1

This is my first encountered from Firebase. I am not sure what this error and no instruction from Firebase. There is no error in my code and I did not know what I suppose to do.
